# Why was integer to string conversion not explicitly included in C++ until now?

Tags: c++, c, string, c++11, string-conversion

One of the first issues I encountered when learning C++ was that the `itoa` function was supported on some compilers but was not actually defined in the ANSI-C standard (and therefore was generally considered bad practice to use).

I have seen multiple solutions such as using `stringstream` or `snprintf`, which have always felt very roundabout to me, and finally in C++11 there is `std::to_string` which feels much cleaner from a language perspective.

But why did it take so long for a more direct method to be added? I have had trouble finding anything beyond some discussions of efficiency and lack of desire to change the standard without good reason.  Was anything ever officially stated on why this was not included or why they finally decided to add it in C++11?  Has there been any discussion of adding this to a future revision of C?

Comment: Well, part of the problem is dynamic memory allocation.  No C APIs other than `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` allocate memory for you.  Converting an integer to a string requires writing the array of characters somewhere, and the C way is to make you pass a buffer to do that.  Hence `sprintf` and `snprintf`.  Plus there's the issue of how to format it, etc.  C++ started with much of the C mindset, and it's taken a long time to really get over it.  These days, it's possible to write an entire application with dynamic memory management with scarcely a call to `new`...

Comment: @JoeZ: these days, one should expect that applications will not explicitly call `new` except in their stop-gap implementation of `make_unique` anticipating C++14 ;-) Of course there will be exceptions, for example apps that use custom smart pointers.

Comment: It's not opinion based, although it is somewhat ignorance based. The fact that neither Konrad or I knows the rationale for sure (but have answered anyway with what we do know) doesn't mean there isn't a reason. This question has basically been closed as "too difficult".

Comment: For a long time C++'s strategy was to just prepare primitives, making tools is up to the other developers. You can always have boost, Poco, Qt, ... . Let the language lives small. On the other hand, judging about strings is always hard. C++ still hasn't a real string type.

Comment: @MM: It's got `std::u32string`, that's a real string type. Just not an overwhelmingly useful one ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, but even C++ itself doesn't support them as a uniform type. For example, you can not open a file which its name is a wide-char string by `ifstream/oftream`.

Comment: @SteveJessop : That's what I was attempting to get at (if inexpertly in the tight space of a comment).  C was very much a "you get memory and we'll scribble on it if you ask us to" language.  C++ started from that legacy, but has ended up someplace very different.  Now, with move semantics, nice containers, smart/unique pointers, etc. it's actually reasonable to return a `string` from something in C++ and not feel woefully out of place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hindsight, it was an oversight. However, without knowing details about the development history of C++, I’d venture the guess that this oversight has good reasons, rooted in theory. See, a conversion from number to string and vice versa is far from trivial, and it doesn’t fit the normal definition of a “cast” very well (in reality, it requires a parser / formatter), even though most other languages *do* provide such a cast.

Added to that is the fact that C++’ support for string types is rather … pedestrian. C doesn’t even have a real, dedicated type for it, it uses `char` arrays instead. C++ goes *slightly* further but stops well short of proper built-in string support. This can be seen in many aspects, from the fact that the string literal is still a null-terminated `char` array, to the broad consensus that `std::string` has a bloated, poorly designed interface. And don’t forget that `std::string` doesn’t even represent a string! It represents an array of bytes! This is an important distinction, and the reason for this is simply that `std::string` is completely encoding agnostic.

Ah, but C++ actually *does* support proper encoding, and proper parsing and formatting. It simply doesn’t provide it for strings – it provides it for *streams*.

And there we have it. C++ has no proper string type. Instead, it has input/output streams.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it's solely a question of how many ways you want there to be to convert an integer to base 10 digits. C++ inherited one from C (`sprintf`) and added one of its own `operator<<(ostream &, int)`. Both of these are more configurable than the new `to_string`, so I suspect it just didn't occur at the time of C++98/03 that they were inadequate.

There were no formal changes to the C++ standard between 2003 and 2011 (some widely-acknowledged errata and that's it), so another part of why it took so long as is that C++0x took so long, and that was for reasons that have nothing to do with `to_string` in particular. `boost::lexical_cast` filled that gap to some extent.